# AngularJS: how to change scope in one controller with trigger in the other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two Controllers and one shared Service.
First Controller renders some text. Other Controller has a button that had to change the First Controllers scope and rerender text (with new value)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
  Value is: {{object}}
</div>

<div ng-controller="Controller2">
  <button ng-click="changeValue()">Click to change Value</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function Controller1($scope, mainServices) {
  $scope.object = mainServices.getValue();
};

function Controller2($scope, mainServices) {

 $scope.changeValue = function(){
   mainServices.getValue('Hello');
   console.log('button is pressed');
 };

};


testApp.factory('mainServices', function(){
 return {

    getValue: function(update) {
     var defaultValue = 'Hi';

     if( typeof(update)==='undefined') {    value = defaultValue;   }
       else {   value = update; }

    console.log('should be changed to', update);
    return value;
   }
}    
 });
```

On Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/IWBEvAfvLbzJ0UD2IqGB?p=preview

Why doesn't this work? How to tell Angular to watch for changes?

Comment: But I hope this is just some sample code, it would be easier to have just one controller with this...

Comment: Sure, in real app this controllers in diffirent views

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The code

Well, I think this is not the best solution, but it is possible for your problem.
Instead of just changing the value itself, you have to create an object before the return statement in the factory.

```
var obj = {}
```

And then you just change a property of this object:

```
if( typeof(update)==='undefined') { obj.val = defaultValue; }
    else {  obj.val = update;   }
```

And return the object:

```
return obj;
```

The other controller can be left unaffected, however you have to change your html:
You have to put in

```
{{object.val}}
```

in order to listen to changes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rjsrkbaQ8QyWGGFI9HYl?p=preview

## Why does this work?

It is quite simple: In javascript, if you call a function with a primitive return value like a string (yes, strings CAN be primitives in javascript), it is just a copy of this primitive, so with

```
$scope.object = mainServices.getValue();
```

you just pass a value to $scope.object, which is not affected by other calls of getValue()
But if we return an object from getValue(), we get a reference to this object. So if we  make changes to this referenced object in getValue(), angularjs will be able to notice the changed object because it is tracked in both controllers.
Therefore we have to reference the same object again and again, but since javascript supports closures, this is pretty easy.

Comment: Well, it is the nature of JS that it is sometimes confusing, but has amazing solutions :D

Comment: @DerWaldschrat great explanation. but what about watching for object changes not for view updating , rather for changing model . `$watch("object.val")` ?

Comment: Well, to admit, I am not an expert concerning angularjs, but according to the docs, that should just work as you suggested with $scope.$watch("object.val", listener) :)